# Rotational Dynamics: Deriving an equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, angular-velocity

I have a problem. A physics problem.

This is the task:

> A box with mass $m$ is on a rotation surface which is smooth and flat. The box is initially at a distance $r$ from the rotation axis of the surface. The coefficient of static friction between the box and the surface is $\mu$. The angular speed of the turntable is gradually increased until the box starts to slide. The box slides outward.
>
> Derive an expression for the angular speed $\omega$ of the turntable at which the box begins to slide.

What I did was I considered the force acting on the box at the time in which it slides off, which is the centripetal force and the static force. So I equated both equations together as the box will start to slide off when the centripetal force overcomes the static force. The equation I got is

$$m \cdot \omega^2 \cdot r = m \cdot g \cdot \mu$$

then I rearranged that to make the angular velocity the subject

$$\omega = \sqrt\frac{g \cdot \mu}{r}$$

which I was fairly certain was correct but I looked at the marking sheet and it says it should be

$$\omega = \sqrt{g \cdot \mu \cdot r}$$

Was wondering if someone can point out if I made any mistake or missed any step to get the final answer. How could I confirm that my analysis is correct?

Comment: Welcome. I made some edits to your question - please visit the help center to understand what kinds of  questions are considered "good", how to format equations, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, and the marking sheet is wrong.

This can be confirmed with simple dimensional analysis: the expression in the marking sheet has dimensions of

$$\sqrt{g\cdot\mu\cdot r} = \left(L \cdot T^{-2}\cdot 1 \cdot L\right)^{\frac12}= L T^{-1}$$

which are the units of velocity.

Your expression, with $r$ in the denominator, gives units of $T^{-1}$ which are the units of angular velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.
Sqrt(g*u*r) is dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: PS I couldn't see floris's answer so I pretty much repeated the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that we do have an [equation editor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) built into the site, which can help improve readability of your post.